# Erro ao Colocar Aplicação em Produção com Comando - mvn spring-boot:run

Tags: java

Depois de gerar o build o que deu tudo certo, estou tentando executar o comando mvn spring-boot:run
Dentro de uma pasta estou apenas com o arquivo 
comunicacaolegado-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar

Ao executar o comando ele começa a processar , mas logo está dando este erro abaixo :

> No plugin found for prefix 'spring-boot' in the current project and in t
>   he plugin groups [org.apache.maven.plugins, org.codehaus.mojo] available from th
>   e repositories [local (C:\Users\Usuario.m2\repository), central (https://repo.m
>   aven.apache.org/maven2)] -> [Help 1]

Estou me debatendo deste as 12:00 de hoje e sem sucesso. Algúem consegue dar uma ajuda o que posso fazer para resolver este problema ? Estou executando isso ,pois irei colocar rodando a aplicação no meu computador mesmo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Depois de gerar o build o que deu tudo certo, estou tentando executar o comando
>   mvn spring-boot:run Dentro de uma pasta estou apenas com o arquivo
>   comunicacaolegado-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar

Ao executar comando: *mvn **spring-boot**:**run***...

O Maven primeiro precisa encontrar o arquivo onde estão as configurações Maven para este projeto(pom.xml). Encontrando-o, o Maven irá validar a sintaxe, aplicar suas configurações de variáveis, configurar plugins padrões, configurar novos plugins, etc. Quando ao fim deste processo, tudo estando ok, o Maven saberá como gerenciar este projeto e solicita ao plugin **spring-boot** que execute o **goal** *run*.

Como nesta pasta não tem o arquivo que orienta o Maven, ele está te falando: - Cara, você está mandando executar esse tal plugin com esse tal goal, mas eu não tenho nem por onde começar e não sei como te ajudar.

Agora, partindo-se do princípio que o seu artefato(comunicacaolegado-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar) segue a estrutura de um projeto Spring Boot e foi "buildado" da forma correta, basta dar um duplo clique sobre o .jar e o projeto irá executar (sabiamente com o S.O. configurado para qualquer .jar ser executado pela JRE), ou, basta abrir aquele seu programa de linha de comando preferido, entrar na pasta contendo o seu .jar e executar: **java -jar comunicacaolegado-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar**.

Links:
https://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/maven-in-five-minutes.html
https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-running-your-application.html

Comment: Bruno, com o comando que você falou deu certo mesmo. java -jar comunicacaolegado-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar. Tentei de toda e qualquer forma utilizar o mvn spring-boot:run e não funcionou. Com o comando que você passou fiz um teste até mesmo em um cliente remoto que está em outro local e a aplicação subiu sem problema. Obrigado pela atenção.